# Using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING on dynamic form data in PHP

Tags: php, filter-var

I am using jquery library to add dynamic form elements to submit data(to be inserted into MYSQL database.
The JavaScript part is as below:-

```
<div>
 <form method="get" action="testb1.php">
<div id="itemRows">

Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" /> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /> <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" />

</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</div>
<script>

var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
rowNum ++;
var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" > Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
frm.add_qty.value = '';
frm.add_name.value = '';
}
function removeRow(rnum) {
jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}       
</script>

And the PHP part to test the submitted data:-
<?php


$no = count($_GET['qty']);
           for ($i=0; $i <$no ; $i++) { 
            echo $_GET['qty'][$i]."<br>";
            echo $_GET['name'][$i]."<br>";

            }
?>
```

Upto this part is OK. The submitted data is showing as expected.
But if I want to Filter the submitted data like the following I am getting one one element(1st one):-

```
$gcode = filter_var($_GET['qty'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$no = count($gcode);
```

Seems Array problem.
How could I filter the submitted string.
Shall I filter each `$_GET['qty'][$i]` separately?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter variables of an array, you have to use [filter_var_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php).

In your case something like this:

```
$gcode = filter_var_array($_GET['qty'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```